# Wordpress footer widgets not aligned

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a website and I can't figure out why the leftmost footer image is not horizontally aligned with the others. It doesn't seem to be an issue with the dimensions, since other images do the same thing.

Is there some other element on the website causing this behavior? Any suggestions for a fix?

http://ivfway.com/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
#footer-bar1 {
  margin-top: 25px !important;
}
```

Delete this margin and all the images will be aligned